# Erro "ActionController::ParameterMissing", mesmo com form enviando parâmetros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, create

Provavelmente estou deixando algo muito besta passar, mas estou tentando encontrar a solução há horas e nada.

Estou criando um CRUD de games. Meu problema está acontecendo na ação `games#create` do meu controller `games`.

Aqui está minha implementação:

**Controller "Games" (app/controllers/games_controller.rb)**

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @games = Game.all
    end

    def show
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
        @stories = @game.stories
    end

    def new
        @game = Game.new
    end

    def create
        @game = Game.new(game_params)
        if @game.save
            redirect_to '/'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def game_params
        params.require(:title).permit(:logo, :start_screen_bg, :start_screen_bgm)
    end

end
```

Estou tentando executar a ação `create` por meio de um form na view `new` desse controller.

**View "new" do controller Games (app/views/games/new.html.erb)**

```
<h1>Create New Game</h1>

<%= form_for (@game) do |g|%>
    <%= g.text_field :title %></br>
    <%= g.text_field :logo, :placeholder => "Logo URL" %></br>
    <%= g.text_field :start_screen_bg, :placeholder => "start screen bg" %></br>
    <%= g.text_field :start_screen_bgm, :placeholder => "start screen bgm" %></br>
    <%= g.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Quando dou submit, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in GamesController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: title
Extracted source (around line #27):
25
26
27
28
29
30

    private
    def game_params
        params.require(:title).permit(:logo, :start_screen_bg, :start_screen_bgm)
    end

end

Rails.root: E:/Projetos/

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/games_controller.rb:27:in `game_params'
app/controllers/games_controller.rb:17:in `create'
Request
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"3fMm6sbdqrgaYZIapN3jHb0Tq0AhslKcrVze1LWLMWpNhm2usUPCh8UXKTBg1Kzpt2Lrq5EGr+egyFxeUGuzwg==",
 "game"=>
  {"title"=>"A New Game",
   "logo"=>"https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
   "start_screen_bg"=>"https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
   "start_screen_bgm"=>"https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"},
 "commit"=>"Create"}
```

Como é possível ver pela seção "Parameters", o parâmetro requerido `:title` está sendo enviado.

Testei comentar a linha `params.require(:title).permit(:logo, :start_screen_bg, :start_screen_bgm)`. O registro é criado com sucesso, porém vazio.

Sinto que é algo muito simples que estou deixando passar...

Alguém passou por um problema parecido? Podem me ajudar?

Abraços!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno, essa chamada `params` `require` `permit` chama-se *strong parameters*.

Na primeira parte, você deve referenciar o nome da classe.
mude de `params.require(:title)` para `params.require(:game)`

na segunda parte você deve colocar os atributos.
adicione o `title` aqui, como mostra abaixo.

```
permit(:logo, :start_screen_bg, :start_screen_bgm, :title)
```

Ao final você deve ter algo assim

```
params.require(:game).permit(:logo, :start_screen_bg, :start_screen_bgm, :title)
```

**Dica**
`require` o Modelo (:game)
`permit` os atributos do modelo

Como você mesmo informa o attributo title está sendo enviado. Correto.
Sua página envia o modelo title.
Porém seu controller não está permitindo ele corretamente.